# Compose decorators applied to class-based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a hierarchy of permission checks and views that need to be protected by them. For example, consider these two checks.

```
def has_profile(user):
    return user.profile is not None

def is_a_sorcerer(user):
    return user.profile.category == 'sorcerer'
```

Note that it only makes sense to call `is_a_sorcerer` if the user has a profile.

Some views should be accessible to anyone with a profile, some views restricted further to only sorcerers.

```
class ProfileView(View):
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(has_profile))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class SorcererView(ProfileView):
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(is_a_sorcerer))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, note that due to inheritance, `is_a_sorcerer` will be called *before* `has_profile` and error out.

It is possible to check for `has_profile` in `is_a_sorcerer`:

```
def is_a_sorcerer(user):
    return has_profile(user) and user.profile.category == 'sorcerer'
```

While this fixes the error, it results in checking `has_profile` twice, and with more than two level of checks the overhead accumulates quickly.

How to compose these decorators without duplicating code? I would still like to keep the permission checks as functions so that they can be applied to function-based views.

Comment: What is the problem with that inheritance? If a user has no profile, it can not be a sorcerer, can it?
In `is_a_sorcerer` implementation you should check if `has_profile` too.

Comment: Using [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) is not an option?

Comment: Adding the `permission_required` decorator to views would not be different from `user_passes_test`, and will still have to check the permissions twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, I would simply check `has_profile` in the `is_a_sorcerer` method. The overhead of checking `has_profile` twice will be negligible.

```
def is_a_sorcerer(user):
    return has_profile(user) and user.profile.category == 'sorcerer'
```

It is possible to avoid running the check twice, but I don't think you'll be able to use the decorators. Instead, you could change the `ProfileView` so that it checks a list of tests. Then override the list of tests in the subclass.

```
class ProfileView(View):
    user_tests = [has_profile]

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for test_func in self.user_tests:
            if not test_func(self.request.user):
                return redirect('login')
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class SorcererView(ProfileView):
    user_tests = ProfileView.user_tests + [is_a_sorcerer]
```

Note that this is less conventional and perhaps more fragile/error prone. It would be easy to forget to include `ProfileView.user_tests` when overriding `user_tests` in the subclass.

Comment: In practice, the decorators do perform database calls which are not necessarily cached. The `user_tests` approach is something I was thinking about too, it's a pity it's not a default.